# Liferay's marketplace-portlet not deployed correctly in version 6.2?

Tags: liferay, liferay-hook

I have created a hook for Liferay 6.1 without errors and now I am trying to do the same for version 6.1

When I deployed the hook in my bundled version, I got the next logs:

```
16:02:36,799 INFO  [com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.auto.AutoDeployScanner][HookAutoDeployListener:56] Hook for D:\liferay-portal-6.2.0-ce-ga1\deploy\encrypted-autologin-hook-1.0.war copied successfully. Deployment will start in a few seconds.
16:02:43,155 INFO  [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]][HotDeployEvent:130] Plugin encrypted-autologin-hook requires marketplace-portlet
16:02:43,156 INFO  [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]][HookHotDeployListener:944] Hook for encrypted-autologin-hook was unregistered
16:02:43,157 INFO  [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]][PluginPackageUtil:1016] Reading plugin package for encrypted-autologin-hook
16:02:44,285 INFO  [localhost-startStop-4][HotDeployEvent:130] Plugin encrypted-autologin-hook requires marketplace-portlet
16:02:44,286 INFO  [localhost-startStop-4][HotDeployImpl:195] Deploying encrypted-autologin-hook from queue
16:02:44,287 INFO  [localhost-startStop-4][PluginPackageUtil:1016] Reading plugin package for encrypted-autologin-hook
16:02:44,490 INFO  [localhost-startStop-4][HookHotDeployListener:687] Registering hook for encrypted-autologin-hook
16:02:44,494 INFO  [localhost-startStop-4][HookHotDeployListener:814] Hook for encrypted-autologin-hook is available for use.
```

As we can see, the message: `Plugin encrypted-autologin-hook requires marketplace-portlet` 
appears. The [documentation](https://www.liferay.com/es/documentation/liferay-portal/6.2/development/-/ai/creating-a-hook-liferay-portal-6-2-dev-guide-10-en) explains that it means we need to install the marketplace-portlet (that already is installed).

I have followed the documentation steps, I have downloaded the Plugin SDK (same version of my Liferay), I have compiled it and I have obtained a WAR file. I have also followed same steps for 'portal-compat-hook' only to be sure. And finally I have installed both war packages.

But, when I redeploy my hook, same logs lines appear. There is any known issue in the marketplace-portlet?

Seems that my hook is not working (no actions observed) and it is also not logging nothing, in spite of following the [Liferay logging guide](https://www.liferay.com/es/documentation/liferay-portal/6.2/user-guide/-/ai/liferays-logging-system-liferay-portal-6-2-user-guide-18-en). Then I assume that the hook is not executed and the only error shown is the lack of the marketplace-portlet. Then why this error appear despite of this portlet already is installed in the bundle and even also if you install it again?

Comment: Note: when I install the marketplace-portlet no errors are reported.

Comment: That is only `INFO`, that is ok. It must be another error. What should do the hook? Why do you mean that is not working? Usuals fail is that several hooks are with similar name is deployed.

Comment: Then is not an error, only a default message? I will take a look elsewhere to see where the error is. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Yes, only default message.

Comment: The [official documentation](http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.2/development/-/ai/creating-a-hook-liferay-portal-6-2-dev-guide-10-en) claims this is solveable by adding the Plugin SDK and then portlet to Eclipse. Look for the first "Note:". I can't get it to work, but if you can, I'd be very interested in your solution for solving the marketplace-portlet importing dependencies.

Comment: @Mark was correct. It is a `INFO` default message. The error was in my hook that is not working correctly and the logger was not enabled in Liferay (then, seems that is not doing anything).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Mark was correct. This message can be safely ignored. The error was elsewhere. Now it is working correctly (and the message is still shown).

Comment: to remove the error, open `/liferay-plugins-sdk-6.2/webs/resources-importer-web/docroot/WEB-INF/liferay-releng.properties` and make sure `marketplace=false`